# Algorithm for dynamic linear regression with stochastic volatility?

Tags: estimation, heteroscedasticity, state-space-models, volatility-forecasting, dynamic-regression

Is there any paper or textbook on how to estimate dynamic linear regression model with stochastic volatility?

The observation equation and state equation,
$$Y_t = \beta_t'X_t + \epsilon_{t}$$
$$\beta_t = \phi\beta_{t-1}' + \eta_{t}$$

where $Y_t$ and $X_t$ are observed, $\eta_{t} \sim N(0,\sigma_{\eta}^2)$

Stochastic volatility components about $\epsilon_{t}$ ,
$$\epsilon_{t} = e^{\frac{h_t}{2}}\gamma_t$$
$$h_t = \mu_h + \tau(h_{t-1}-\mu_h) + \psi_t$$

where $\gamma_t\sim N(0,1)$ and $\psi_t\sim N(0,\sigma_\psi^2)$

I know how to estimate each model separately. Thanks.

Comment: Do $N$ and $Normal$ differ?

Comment: @RichardHardy  They are the same, normal distribution. I've updated.